# Why does this open cover of $T^n$ have intersection $T^{n-1}\sqcup T^{n-1}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

When computing the de Rham cohomology of the $n$-torus $T^n$, usually one takes an open cover $T^n=A\cup B$, where $A=T^{n-1}\times S^1\setminus{N}$ and $B=T^{n-1}\times S^1\setminus\{S\}$, where we've subtracted the north or south pole of the last factor of $S^1$.

In applying the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, every source I find says $A\cap B$ has cohomology group the same as that of $T^{n-1}\sqcup T^{n-1}$. But isn't $A\cap B=T^{n-1}\times S^1\setminus\{N,S\}$, which retracts to just $T^{n-1}$? Why would we get two disjoint copies?

Comment: Have you tried to visualize the case $n=2$? You get a (regular) torus with two circles removed.

Comment: $S^1\setminus\{N,S\}$ has two components!

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking right, so you only have to note that $$T^{n-1} \times (S^1-\{N,S\}) \cong T^{n-1} \times ((0,\frac 12)\sqcup (\frac 12,1)) \simeq T^{n-1} \times \{0,1\}$$

and the latter term is by definition disjoint union.